# This file looks fine with the more command. Why do I see all of these extra characters in vim?

Tags: encoding

I just opened a file and found what looked like a bunch of garbage at the beginning and ending of each line:

```
^[[35m^[[KsampleA.trimmed.count.20_to_30.not_in_ref.MULTI_in_sample.sam^[[m^[[K^[[36m^[[K:^[[m^[[K7
^[[35m^[[KsampleA.trimmed.count.20_to_30.not_in_ref.in_sample.sam^[[m^[[K^[[36m^[[K:^[[m^[[K4
...
```

I was wondering if Vim was in some funny UTF-8 mode or something.

This file was simply created using `grep` on Linux:

```
grep -c 'NM:i:0' *.sam > grep_example.txt
```

They look fine with `more`:

[image: Image with the command "more grep_example.txt" followed by two lines in color showing the results.]

But it has all these funny characters when using `vim`:
[image: Image showing the vim console with "extra" characters before and after the text that shows up as colored with more]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those characters are actually color encoding. Don't you think it odd that when you type `more` you get color instead of black-and-white characters?

You must have `grep` set as an alias to `grep --color=always`. You're probably going to want to make a separate grep alias for viewing results in the console versus extracting text from files.

Basically, vim is being honest and showing you the actual characters in the file. More is also honest, but it sends those characters to your console, which interprets them as color encoding instead of text.